# How create style from Grid with textblocks

Tags: wpf, xaml

i have grid like this:

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="580" Margin="10,402,10,48">
<TextBlock Text="0-10 V" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="10,10,470,65"/>
<TextBlock Text="Czestotliwosc:" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Width="110" Height="25" Margin="10,40,460,35"/>
<TextBlock Text="0 Hz" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="135,40,345,35"/>
<TextBlock Text="Stan czujnika:" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Width="120" Height="25" Margin="10,70,450,5"/>
<TextBlock Text="brak" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="0,70,345,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

And create style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="NamurSensorNamur" TargetType="Grid">
<Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="580"/>
</Style>
```

But i dont know how property had I to use to declarate this textblocks.

I the future i want create dynamiclly this grid by

```
Style={DynamicResource NamurSensorNamur}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, try to edit it and describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: make a UserControl instead. or a DataTemplate

Comment: How it doesn't make sense? I wanted create style for my grid. To assigning it give me Grid with texblock inside or other controls. Because I couldn't find the answer i create layout not dynamiclly, and hide unnecessary controls. And it is enoght for me. But if someone know answer, I will thanksful.